# What is the distribution of similarites between 2 iterations of a binomial variable?

Tags: binomial-distribution, differences

Suppose I have a binary vector $v$ of dimension $n$ with $np$ entries set to $1$ and $n(1-p)$ entries set to $0$ (where $0 \leq p \leq 1$, and $q:=1-p$).

Suppose I then generate a random vector $w$ by random sampling from flipping a $p$-weighted coin $n$ times. I then calculate the Hamming distance $d$ between $v$ and $w$.

What is the expected distribution of $d$?

---

I think the chance of getting an exact match is given by following: $p^{np} \cdot q^{nq}$.

And can calculate the chance of being off-by-1 in a similar way: $\binom{np}{1}p^{np-1}q^{nq+1} + \binom{nq}{1}p^{np+1}q^{nq-1}$.

To find the distribution of $d$ - do the above calculations have to be repeated for all possible values of $d$? Or is there any easier way to estimate the error?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer looks correct to me. I don't think you can do any better than expressing it as a sum:
$$
\Pr(D=d)=\sum_{j=\max\{0,d-nq\} }^{\min\{d,np\}} {np \choose j} {nq \choose d-j} p^{np+d-2j} q^{nq-d+2j}
$$
Is it, however, much easier to work out $\mathbb{E}(D)$ using the linearity of expectation.